# Requesting Json

Tags: json, python-requests

when i put this link : https://www.sofascore.com/basketball/livescore/json?_=159726531 in google
i got JSON data. So I request this link:

```
import json
import time
import requests

url = "https://www.sofascore.com/basketball/livescore/json?_=159729590"
headers = {
           "referer": "https://www.google.pl/", 
             "user-agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
             "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
             "accept-language": "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7", 
             "authority": "www.sofascore.com",
             "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
             "method": "GET",
             "scheme": "https",
             "accept": "*/*",
           }
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#dict_obj = json.loads(page.text)
#print(dict_obj)
```

I didn't get even text but i got response 200. What i did wrong?

Comment: You would need to use proxies. When I tried I got blocked

Comment: I've been using proxies and setting up cookies by object session() but always got response 403. Maybe Selenium with headline mode is good solution?

Comment: Could be. Try it out